# Make UITextView scrollable

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, interface-builder, uitextview

This seems so dumb, but I checked all the boxes that I have found as "solutions" to similar problems but nothing is quite working.  I have a UITextView box that I want to be scrollable, and my settings are below.  Anyone know why it isn't letting me scroll?

[image: Scrollable fail]

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that you do not have enough content to make the scrollbars appear.

Comment: if you always want it to bounce, just check the "Always bounce...", it isn't scrollable but you can move it in each direction.

Comment: I've tried adding 3x the amount of text necessary to fill the textview and still won't let me scroll.  I've tried turning on "always bounce" and it still didn't do anything :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please also make sure that User Interaction Enabled is checked in .xib file

Comment: There are 2 User Interaction Enable boxes.  Just so anyone else knows, they BOTH need to be check marked.  I only had one and it was causing my error.

Comment: To clarify further, there's one under the Identity inspector and one under the Attributes inspector.

Comment: @smacdonald you need to check which is under Attribute inspector, for identity inspector accessibility you can read here http://mattgemmell.com/accessibility-for-iphone-and-ipad-apps/

Answer (score 3):

I also had a problem with an unscrollable `UITextView`, but the other answers here didn't help (granted it was a special case: I only needed to scroll when the app was viewed horizontally).

Just in case anyone has a similar problem and lands here: what did help me was to activate vertical `Autosizing` (`Size Inspector` under `View`) for the textview.

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure you have text in your UITextView
- Check to see if the UITextView is enabled (there's a property in settings) - it should be enabled.

Make sure you don't change these settings (or the "Scrolling Enabled" property) in your code.

Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

you have to actually have texts inside the textview that overlap it original frame height to make it scrollable

Comment: I make up spam strings just to fill it up 3x over and it still isn't scrollable.  Is there perhaps a glitch in my frameheight?  If so, how would i check that.

Comment: i can't really help much since im not on my mac.. but try setting the userinteraction property of the textview to YES